Django exception, NoReverseMatch
I'm learning django on a small project called BlogPost from a python's book. This is a very simple project on its own - user can add a post with title and text.
I'm trying to add functionality of editting existed entries via views.py function called "edit_entry" and i receive exception which i can't overcome:
NoReverseMatch at /edit_entry/6/
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_entry/6/
Raised during:  blogs.views.edit_entry
Reverse for 'edit_entry' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_entry/(?P<object_id>[0-9]+)/\Z']
Does anybody know what could be a proble?
Here is my code:
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    """Create data model"""
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic

forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import BlogPost

class NewEntryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['topic','text']
        labels = {'topic':'Topic', 'text': 'Text'}

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('entries/', views.entries, name='entries'),
    path('new_entry/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
    path('edit_entry/<int:object_id>/', views.edit_entry, name='edit_entry')]

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import request
from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import NewEntryForm

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    """Show main page"""

    return render(request, "blogs/index.html")

def entries(request):
    """Shows all entries based on pub. date"""

    object = BlogPost.objects.all()

    context = {'objects': object}
    return render(request,"blogs/entries.html", context)

def new_entry(request):
    """To add new entry"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = NewEntryForm()
    else:
        form = NewEntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blogs:entries')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/new_entry.html', context)

def edit_entry(request, object_id):
    """To edit existed entry"""
    entry = BlogPost.objects.get(id=object_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = NewEntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        form = NewEntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blogs:entries', object_id=object.id)

    context={'form':form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/edit_entry.html', context)

entries.html
{% extends "blogs/base.html"%}}

{% block content %}

    <h3>Your entries:</h3>
    <button name="new_entry"><a href="{% url 'blogs:new_entry' %}">New entry</a></button>

    <ul>
        {% for object in objects %}
        <li>
            <p>Title: {{ object.topic }}</p>
            <p>Date: {{ object.date_added }}</p>
            <p>Text: {{ object.text }}</p>
            <p><a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_entry' object.id %}">Edit</a></p>
        </li>

        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

{% endblock %}

edit_entries.html
{% extends "blogs/base.html"%}}

{% block content %}

<h2> You can edit your entries here</h2>


#<form action="{% url 'blogs:edit_entry' object.id %}" method="post">
#    {% csrf_token %}
#    {{ form.as_p }}
#    <button name="submit">save</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}

enter image description here
I can't understand the problem. I have a hypothesis that something wrong in edit_entry function.

Change return redirect('blogs:entries', object_id=object.id) to return redirect('blogs:entries', object_id=object_id) in your edit_entry function.

raphael, i've tried, same problem. Are you sure  object_id=object_id could work?

Your view, edit_entry doesn't define object so I guessed it would be blank, leading to the error.  However, I don't think you need any of this at all since you are redirecting to the same view (which is fine).  In this case you can probably replace return redirect('blogs:entries', object_id=object_id) with simply return redirect('blogs:entries') and your <form action="{% url 'blogs:edit_entry' object.id %}" method="post"> with <form method="post">.  Removing the action simply takes you back to the original page anyway.

@raphael  thank you! removing "ation" from form and object_id from edit_entry made it work!
